# How to integrate Custom CA (AWS PCA) using Kubernetes CSR in Istio

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

am trying to setup Custom CA (AWS PCA) Integration using Kubernetes CSR in Istio following this doc (Istio / Custom CA Integration using Kubernetes CSR). Steps followed:

i) Enable feature gate on cert-manager controller: --feature-gates=ExperimentalCertificateSigningRequestControllers=true

ii) AWS PCA and aws-privateca-issuer plugin is already in place.

iii) awspcaclusterissuers object in place with AWS PCA arn (arn:aws:acm-pca:us-west-2:<account_id>:certificate-authority/)

iv) Modified Istio operator with defaultConfig and caCertificates of AWS PCA issuer (awspcaclusterissuers.awspca.cert-manager.io/)

v) Modified istiod deployment and added env vars (as mentioned in the doc along with cluster role).

**istiod pod is failing with this error:**

```
Generating K8S-signed cert for [istiod.istio-system.svc istiod-remote.istio-system.svc istio-pilot.istio-system.svc] using signer awspcaclusterissuers.awspca.cert-manager.io/cert-manager-aws-root-ca
2023-01-04T07:25:26.942944Z error   failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: no certificate returned for the CSR: "csr-workload-lg6kct8nh6r9vx4ld4"
Error: failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: no certificate returned for the CSR: "csr-workload-lg6kct8nh6r9vx4ld4"
```

K8s Version: 1.22
Istio Version: 1.13.5
Note: Our integration of cert manager and AWS PCA works fine as we generate Private Certificates using cert-manager and PCA with ‘Certificates’ object. It’s the integration of kubernetes csr method with istio that is failing!

Would really appreciate if anybody with knowledge on this could help me out here as there are nearly zero docs on this integration.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with Kubernetes CSR, but I have done it with [Istio CSR](https://github.com/cert-manager/istio-csr). Here are the steps to accomplish it with this approach.

1. Create a certificate in AWS Private CA and download the public root certificate either via the console or AWS CLI (`aws acm-pca get-certificate-authority-certificate --certificate-authority-arn <certificate-authority-arn> --region af-south-1 --output text > ca.pem`).
2. Create a secret to store this root certificate. Cert manager will use this public root cert to communicate with the root CA (AWS PCA).
3. Install cert-manager. Cert manager will essentially function as the intermediate CA in place of istiod.
4. Install [AWS PCA Issuer plugin](https://github.com/cert-manager/aws-privateca-issuer).
5. Make sure you have the necessary permissions in place for the workload to communicate with AWS Private CA. The recommended approach would be to use OIDC with [IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html). The other approach is to grant permissions to the node role. The problem with this is that any pod running on your nodes essentially has access to AWS Private CA, which isn't a least privilege approach.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "awspcaissuer",
            "Action": [
                "acm-pca:DescribeCertificateAuthority",
                "acm-pca:GetCertificate",
                "acm-pca:IssueCertificate"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:acm-pca:<region>:<account_id>:certificate-authority/<resource_id>"
        }       
    ]
}
```

6. Once the permissions are in place, you can create a cluster issuer or an issuer that will represent the root CA in the cluster.

```
apiVersion: awspca.cert-manager.io/v1beta1
kind: AWSPCAClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: aws-pca-root-ca
spec:
  arn: <aws-pca-arn-goes-here>
  region: <region-where-ca-was-created-in-aws>
```

7. Create the istio-system namespace
8. Install Istio CSR and update the Helm values for the issuer so that cert-manager knows to communicate with the AWS PCA issuer.

```
helm install -n cert-manager cert-manager-istio-csr jetstack/cert-manager-istio-csr \
    --set "app.certmanager.issuer.group=awspca.cert-manager.io" \
    --set "app.certmanager.issuer.kind=AWSPCAClusterIssuer" \
    --set "app.certmanager.issuer.name=aws-pca-root-ca" \
    --set "app.certmanager.preserveCertificateRequests=true" \
    --set "app.server.maxCertificateDuration=48h" \
    --set "app.tls.certificateDuration=24h" \
    --set "app.tls.istiodCertificateDuration=24h" \
    --set "app.tls.rootCAFile=/var/run/secrets/istio-csr/ca.pem" \
    --set "volumeMounts[0].name=root-ca" \
    --set "volumeMounts[0].mountPath=/var/run/secrets/istio-csr" \
    --set "volumes[0].name=root-ca" \
    --set "volumes[0].secret.secretName=istio-root-ca"
```

I would also recommend setting `preserveCertificateRequests` to true at least for the first time you set this up so that you can actually see the CSRs and whether or not the certificate were successfully issued.

When you install Istio CSR, this will create a certificate called `istiod` as well as a corresponding secret that stores the cert. The secret is called `istiod-tls`. This is the cert for the intermediate CA (Cert manager with Istio CSR).
9) Install Istio with the following custom configurations:

- Update the CA address to Istio CSR (the new intermediate CA)
- Disable istiod from functioning as the CA
- Mount istiod with with the cert-manager certificate details

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  profile: "demo"
  hub: gcr.io/istio-release
  values:
   global:
     # Change certificate provider to cert-manager istio agent for istio agent
    caAddress: cert-manager-istio-csr.cert-manager.svc:443
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
          # Disable istiod CA Sever functionality
        - name: ENABLE_CA_SERVER
          value: "false"
        overlays:
        - apiVersion: apps/v1
          kind: Deployment
          name: istiod
          patches:

            # Mount istiod serving and webhook certificate from Secret mount
          - path: spec.template.spec.containers.[name:discovery].args[7]
            value: "--tlsCertFile=/etc/cert-manager/tls/tls.crt"
          - path: spec.template.spec.containers.[name:discovery].args[8]
            value: "--tlsKeyFile=/etc/cert-manager/tls/tls.key"
          - path: spec.template.spec.containers.[name:discovery].args[9]
            value: "--caCertFile=/etc/cert-manager/ca/root-cert.pem"

          - path: spec.template.spec.containers.[name:discovery].volumeMounts[6]
            value:
              name: cert-manager
              mountPath: "/etc/cert-manager/tls"
              readOnly: true
          - path: spec.template.spec.containers.[name:discovery].volumeMounts[7]
            value:
              name: ca-root-cert
              mountPath: "/etc/cert-manager/ca"
              readOnly: true

          - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[6]
            value:
              name: cert-manager
              secret:
                secretName: istiod-tls
          - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[7]
            value:
              name: ca-root-cert
              configMap:
                defaultMode: 420
                name: istio-ca-root-cert
```

If you want to watch a detailed walk-through on how the different components communicate, you can watch this video:
https://youtu.be/jWOfRR4DK8k

In the video, I also show the CSRs and the certs being successfully issued, as well as test that mTLS is working as expected.
*The video is long, but you can skip to **17:08** to verify that the solution works.*

Here's a repo with these same steps, the relevant manfiest files and architecture diagrams describing the flow: https://github.com/LukeMwila/how-to-setup-external-ca-in-istio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is great, but the problem is it doesnt seem to work when Im installing istio with revision flag.